# How do you configure the min instances of Stateless EJB (JBOSS)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a stateless ejb that takes some time to initialize.  To avoid this cost, I'd like there to always be a min number of this EJB instantiated.  Is there something like minInstances that I can configure on a bean basis similar to MDB minInstances? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Anybody?  I've look around prior to posting the question and only found a jboss specific annotation @StatelessDeployment.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the `StrictMaxPool` [implementation](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/ejb3/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/ejb3/pool/strictmax/StrictMaxPool.java) used in Wildfly 10.x, there is no option to set a minimum size.

The XSD wildfly-ejb3_4_0.xsd does also not know something about a min size:

```
<xs:complexType name="strict-max-poolType">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="max-pool-size" type="xs:positiveInteger" default="20" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="derive-size" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="instance-acquisition-timeout" type="xs:positiveInteger" default="5" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="instance-acquisition-timeout-unit" type="timeout-unitType"
                  default="MINUTES" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

On the other hand, the `release` method of the `StricMaxPool` does put all released beans back:

```
public void release(T obj) {
        if (ROOT_LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {
            ROOT_LOGGER.tracef("%s/%s Free instance: %s", pool.size(), maxSize, this);
        }

        pool.add(obj);

        semaphore.release();
    }
```

This means that once you have created `max-pool-size` beans, the pool won't shrink. Hence you can implement some `@Startup` bean that fills the pool during startup.

Comment: Im not sure what to do with the above information.  An review of the logging indicates the session bean in question getting instantiated over and over again.  My reading indicates this is expected.  Basically after a period of in-activity the session bean gets destroyed.

Comment: How do you track that it is instantiated every time again? The lifecycle methods like @PostConstruct are executed after it is taken from the pool, but you don't get a new instance.

Comment: logging in the constructor of the object